# Real time notification on database insertion using servlet , jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, notifications

I am using `Servlet, JSP and JQuery` combination in my application. What I need as follows:

I have a page `Home.jsp` and `insert.jsp`. `Home.jsp` is the home page and `insert.jsp` is the page from where I am inserting values into database. I am using `Postgresql 9.5` as DB.

My requirement is that When ever I insert a value in database using `insert.jsp` page then I should get notification on my `Home.jsp` page.

I am making use of `bootstrap` as well for UI .

What I do is as follows:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get("TestServlet", function(data){
        if(data.trim() == "0"){
            console.log("if");
        }else{
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
      });


}, 5000);
```

My `TestServlet` will return the no: of records in that table. So when ever the user entered home page it will alert `bootstrap modal` as notification. And it keeps on coming every 5 seconds after first entry but I need it should come once
.

Is there any alternate ways for notification? Or any other real time methods using the default `Servlet` methods? please guide me.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I found a useful article http://www.javabeat.net/asynchronous-servlet-servlet-3-0/. But I have doubt on this in example they are specifying on button click. If I do setInterval in place of button click does it make network load more? Please suggest buddy!!

Comment: did you tried `window.onload` or `document.onload` if you want to show pop up only once.